# C++ Observer Mode, "does not name a type" compile error

Tags: c++, class, oop, arduino, observer-pattern

I am writing an Arduino program where LEDs and a bunch of other electronics are controlled by different buttons. To simplify the code, I am using the Observer Mode:

class `Observer` observes `EventThrower`s, who performs `check()` every frame and notifies `Observer`s if necessary. The code definition for `Observer and EventThrower` looks like this:

```cpp
class Observer {
public:
    virtual void handleEvent(int label, bool state) = 0; // Virtual method called by EventThrowers.
};

class EventThrower {
private:
    std::vector<Observer *> observer_list;
protected:
    void notifyObservers(int label, bool state) {
        for (Observer *observer : observer_list) {
            observer->handleEvent(label, state);
        }
    }    
public:
    virtual void check() = 0; // Virtual method used in loop() for frame checking. 

    void addObserver(Observer *_observer) {
        this->observer_list.push_back(_observer);
    }
};
```

And my `LEDCtrl` class (an `Observer`) and `ButtonClick` class (an `EventThrower`) definitions are:

```cpp
class LEDCtrl : public Observer {
public:
    // properties

    LEDCtrl(int _led_pin) { ... } // constructor
    void handleEvent(int label, bool state) { ... } // overridden handleEvent method
    
private:
    void toggleLight(bool new_status) { ... } // assistant method
};

class ButtonClick : public EventThrower {
public:
    // properties

    ButtonClick(int _button_pin, int _default, int _label) { ... } // constructor
    void check() { ... } // overridden check() that is called every frame to check the status of the button and choose to notify Observers or not
};
```

My initialization of a `LEDCtrl`-`ButtonClick` instance pair looks like:

```cpp
ButtonClick *buttonClick1 = new ButtonClick(BUTTON1, 0, 0); 
LEDCtrl *ledCtrl1 = new LEDCtrl(LED1);
buttonClick1->addObserver(ledCtrl1);
```

However, the above code throws this compile error:

```
 error: 'buttonClick1' does not name a type
 buttonClick1->addObserver(ledCtrl1);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you write this outside of any function? At the top (file or namespace) level, you can only have declarations and definitions.

Comment: please add Arduino Tag

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you!!!! That's the case!!! I didn't notice that since they look so alike as declarations 